# dataimport not working from mysql to solr

Tags: solr

verything is have configured properly. but when i run import from mysql to solr and try to index them, it says :-

```
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
Requests: 1, Fetched: 25, Skipped: 0, Processed: 0
Started: about a minute ago
```

here are my xml files :-
**db-data-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/delance" user="root" password="pass" batchSize="1"/>
     <document name="Jobs">
    <entity name="Jobs" query="select * from Jobs">
         <field name="job_title" column="job_title" />
    </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**schema.xml**

```
<field name="job_title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**Jobs Table**

```
Jobs    CREATE TABLE `Jobs` (                                                                         
          `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                                   
          `description` longtext,                                                                     
          `job_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,                                                       
          `job_hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,                                                            
          `job_title` varchar(500),                                                                           
          `time_limit` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,                                                      
          `users_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                                       
          PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`),                                                                     
          KEY `FK2350763B6AF29A` (`users_user_id`),                                                   
          CONSTRAINT `FK2350763B6AF29A` FOREIGN KEY (`users_user_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`user_id`)  
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: whats the uniqueKey in schema.xml?

Comment: i didn't defined uniqueKey, is it necessary. schema.xml contains a default <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>.

Comment: do you have a id field in your schema too?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you are using a field job_title which is not a unique key neither required, so you should use the id required key and set it as unique key, or you should configure the unique key to be auto-incremented.

however to get things properly follow this:
the id field is defined by default, check that it is in your schema.xml and that it is defined as unique key like below :

`<fields>
     <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/> 
     <field name="job_title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
     <!-- other fields definition ... -->
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>`

and also in your entity query you should index an 'id' which is unique of your db table like this:

`<document name="Jobs">
    <entity name="Jobs" query="select * from Jobs">
         <!-- id here should be stirng, or you can change its type in its definition in the schema.xml -->
         <field name="id" column="table_id" /> 
         <field name="job_title" column="job_title" />
    </entity>
 </document>`

this should resolve this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

you got no required neither unique key.
so you may create an autoincrement required id, or create one and add it as an entity field.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined id as the unique key in your schema , then you need to provide that value during the data import

```
<field name="id" column="job_id" />
```